# Can not execute Findbugs: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, while running mvn sonar:sonar -X

Tags: maven, build, out-of-memory, sonarqube

i am trying to do the code analysis in sonar 2.11, using maven 3.

I am facing this error

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

i tried to increase the MAVEN_OPTS to `-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` but no use.

The project is of large size of about 900MB. I am using the command `mvn sonar:sonar -X` in maven 3. But the build is failure.
I am not running the tests or nor using  any surefire plugin in my superPOM. So i am unable to find the cause of the problem.
Please help me to figure out where the problem exixts.
Thanks in advance...
Here is the log...

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] PHOENIX JAVA MODULE COMPONENT ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] PHOENIX JAVA COMPONENT ............................ FAILURE [1:27:23.969s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:27:26.229s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 14 14:14:24 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 287M/1016M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: Can not execute Sonar: Can not execute Findbugs: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: Can not execute Sonar   
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Findbugs
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsSensor.analyse(FindbugsSensor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:93)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:143)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:89)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:110)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:105)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:100)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:89)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:96)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:89)
    at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
    at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.executeBatch(SonarMojo.java:147)
    at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:113)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:112)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:112)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:110)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.vna.ValueNumberFrame.<init>(ValueNumberFrame.java:58)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.vna.ValueNumberAnalysis.createFact(ValueNumberAnalysis.java:148)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.vna.ValueNumberAnalysis.createFact(ValueNumberAnalysis.java:55)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.Dataflow.execute(Dataflow.java:309)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.bcel.ValueNumberDataflowFactory.analyze(ValueNumberDataflowFactory.java:72)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.bcel.ValueNumberDataflowFactory.analyze(ValueNumberDataflowFactory.java:47)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.analyzeMethod(AnalysisCache.java:332)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getMethodAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:282)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ClassContext.getMethodAnalysis(ClassContext.java:942)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ClassContext.getValueNumberDataflow(ClassContext.java:361)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.FindInconsistentSync2.findObviouslyLockedCallSites(FindInconsistentSync2.java:963)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.FindInconsistentSync2.visitClassContext(FindInconsistentSync2.java:311)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DetectorToDetector2Adapter.visitClass(DetectorToDetector2Adapter.java:68)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.analyzeApplication(FindBugs2.java:979)
    at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:230)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :XXX
```

Comment: what does `mvn findbugs:findbugs` give you? and what do you need to set the permgen to on http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/findbugs-mojo.html#jvmArgs to make `findbugs:findbugs` work. I suspect that there is some magic secret sonar config that is equivalent (if it isn't just delegating to `findbugs:findbugs` otherwise you will need to raise a sonar bug"

Comment: @StephenConnolly when i run `mvn findbugs:findbugs` the build failed with this error `Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2:findbugs failed: Java returned: 1`

Comment: So now try altering its configuration with forkMode true, upping the memory (most likely just the permgen) until it doesn't fall over. That will tell you how much memory find bugs needs *without* sonar in the mix... Then you can tune sonar once you have that answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known problem: Findbugs is really memory hungry, so I'm not surprised that with a 900MB project, you have to increase the JVM memory options quite a lot.

3 things you can do:

1. increase again the JVM memory options till it is OK
2. reduce the amount of activated Findbugs rules in your Sonar quality profile
3. refactor your project is smaller modules so that each module requires less memory to get analyzed by Findbugs

If I were you, I'd really go for at least option #3, because 900MB for a single project is really huge.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Option 3 is the only sane option. Of course you can throw in hardware too.

Comment: @Fabrice 1)i tried to increase JVM memory beyond 1GB after which the JVM itself failed to initialize. and the project consists of several modules, but how could i configure which module i need to anlalyse in pom.xml? can u please explain breifly how to set the source directory that is to be analysed in pom.xml?

Comment: another doubt is whether running eclipse parallel to maven build process lead to outofmemory error or java heap space error...?

Comment: By default, Sonar will analyse every module defined in your POM. If you want to exclude some modules, you can use the "sonar.skippedModules" property to do so: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam hi, just now after reviewing the pom file, i found that in the local-build profile only one module is active by default. so there is no question of multiple modules being active simultaneously. so why would i still get the same `java.lang.OutofMemoryError`? and one more fundamental thing... i didn't configure any findbugs plugin in my pom. does it still come into picture when i run mvn sonar:sonar command

Comment: Findbugs is launched by Sonar if you have Findbugs rules in the quality profile that you are using, wether or not it is configured in your POM. If you have an OutOfMemoryError on a single module, this probably means that your module is too big and should be splitted into smaller modules. If you don't want to do so, just remove Findbugs rules from the quality profile in Sonar to reduce the memory use.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam thanks for all your responses... after searching google, i found that we can increase the memory for VM used by findbugs using `-maxHeap n`. for this should i need to have findbugs plugin configured in my pom.xml? earlier i had `Timeout Exception`, and i was able to solve that problem by increasing the Timeout parameter in the sonar web console which is by default 10min. if i have to configure findbugs plugin in my POM, can u please give me the structure of the findbugs plugin? including fork, effort,maxheap parameters.

Comment: i also tried to run this command `mvn sonar:sonar -X -Dmaven.findbugs.jvmargs=-Xmx1500m`, but even this didn't solve the `OutOfMemoryError`. Any suggestions....

Comment: Sonar runs Findbugs directly, so using the Maven plugin properties won't work.

Comment: finally i couldn't solve the issue, so i removed all the findbugs rules from the quality profile. Now the build is successfull. Still i am trying to find out the solution to this problem...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem where it used to hung on Journal Flushing and ultimately timeout at whatever the value i set in Findbags Java default timeout in sonarqube or give Out of memory error.

I resolved this by using the following options while running the sonar maven command:- MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseSerialGC"

This has fixed the issue for me.

The post which helped me:- http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/SonarQube-terminates-at-quot-Journal-Flusher-quot-warning-and-heap-size-error-td5027066.html

Answer (score 0):

Updating the JDK version on jenkins server to 64 bit solved this issue for me.

Try setting the parameter `set SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` in *sonar-scanner.bat*
or `export SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m` if invoking through shell script.